# Cannot resolve symbol 'build' on line import com.android.build.OutputFile in app/build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

So I just created a react native project using the command

`react-native init "project-name"`

I went into the app level build.gradle to connect firebase and I had an error saying could not resolve symbol 'android' on the line

`import com.android.build.OutputFile`

However, it popped up saying "android framework is detected in the project click to configure" so I did this, but then it said cannot resolve symbol 'build' on the same line, I have no idea why it's saying this as I have made the project the same way before and never had this problem, any ideas?

Comment: Where is this `import` line? What file?

Comment: It's in the app level build.gradle, android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Have you tried cleaning (Build->Clean) and rebuilding the project (Build->Rebuild Project) in Android Studio?

Comment: I got the same issue. Did you find out how to solve it?

Answer (score 23):

In my case I was able to solve this by following those steps:

1. Comment out the line like this: `// import com.android.build.OutputFile`
2. Sync the project (click "Sync now")
3. Uncomment the previously commented line: `import com.android.build.OutputFile`
4. Sync again.

This might not work for everybody. In my case said import worked until I changed something somewhere in the project and suddenly the import failed. If the import *never* worked for you, this might not be the solution, but otherwise worth a try.

Comment: I'm really surprised, but this solution worked for me!! Thanks for the posting! My problem was with com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension, but it basically was the same issue.  By the way, I was using that import in a number of places, so I commented out all usages before I ran the gradle sync.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfotunately it' hasn't worked for me...

Answer (score 8):

the thing that worked for me was

**1-** **replace this line in build.gradle(:app)**

```
def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
```

with:

```
def abi = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)
```

**2- and click on sync project with gradle files (the elephant with blue arrow)**

[image]

Comment: As I set import of Output file, it was automatically removing the line for import, replacing this code really helped, Thank you for saving my day!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: @Lauro235 could you give more input, maybe I can help.

Comment: Thanks Shiraz.

I initialised with npx create-react-ntaive-app

"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-auth0": "^2.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.75.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.7"
  },

Android has always had a problem with BuildConfig

I can run app with dev-client, but attempting development builds fail due to build config..

Comment: this might be coming late but here's my try:
1. try my solution
2. try cleaning the project and rebuilding it by selecting Build > clean project and then build > rebuild project from the Android studio menu.
3. select file > invalidate caches / restart from the Android studio menu.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to find the exact problem, go to the Android folder and `assembleRelease` using the terminal window:

```
 cd android
 .\gradlew assembleRelease
```

my problem was with the `crashlytics` package that was needed another version of the `react-native-firebase/app` package

installing the recommended version solved my problem

Comment: ./gradlew assembleRelease -> the ./ before is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try double click on build word in your code such as Build.VERSION, not in the import `com.android.build.OutputFile`. then if it show press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you should do it.

Comment: if i am double clicking then whole word is getting selected.

Answer (score 1):

> Change the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1' to 3.4.2 in your 
>   package build.gradle file

For me, i was using

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

Then i have just changed the version to 3.4.2 an the problem was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure you have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'` in the `dependencies` block of your app level build.gradle file.

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'  should be in the dependencies of Buildscript block not in the dependencies block of app level build.gradle