# Gradle - Unable to load class LibraryExtension

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-custom-plugin

I am trying to create a custom gradle plugin to make use of the gradle conventions for a multi-module project.

I have the ***buildSrc*** module where in the *settings.gradle* file I apply the ["de.fayard.refreshVersions"](https://github.com/jmfayard/refreshVersions) plugin for managing the dependencies versions, while in the *build.gradle* file I registered the custom plugins and using ***kotlin-dsl***.

I firstly tried to move the logic to the ***build-logic*** module following the [nowinandroid](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) project, but, because I am using the refreshVersions plugin, this could not be possible as the plugin does not support it.

The following code shows the *build.gradle* file in which I registered my custom plugin.

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.7.10"

    `kotlin-dsl`

    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version kotlinVersion
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(Android.tools.build.gradlePlugin)
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:_")
    implementation(KotlinX.serialization.json)
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register("feature-plugin") {
            id = "com.example.myapplication.feature-plugin"
            implementationClass = "com.example.myapplication.featureplugin.FeaturePlugin"
        }
        register("hilt-plugin") {
            id = "com.example.myapplication.hilt-plugin"
            implementationClass = "com.example.myapplication.hiltplugin.HiltPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

While the code below is the actual custom plugin in which I applied some plugins, dependencies and, using the ***LibraryExtension***, I configured the app flavours for the modules and some gradle features.

```
package com.example.myapplication.featureplugin

import AndroidX
import Consts
import com.android.build.api.dsl.LibraryExtension
import com.example.myapplication.projectextensions.configureKotlinAndroid
import com.example.myapplication.projectextensions.configureFlavors
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.configure
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.dependencies
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.project

class FeaturePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        with(project) {
            pluginManager.apply {
                apply("com.android.library")
                apply("kotlin-android")
                apply("kotlin-kapt")

                // Custom plugin for Hilt
                apply("com.example.myapplication.hilt-plugin")
            }

           extensions.configure<LibraryExtension> {
               configureKotlinAndroid(this)
               defaultConfig.targetSdk = Consts.AndroidTargetSdk
               configureFlavors(this)
           }

            dependencies {
                add("implementation", AndroidX.core.ktx)
                add("implementation", AndroidX.lifecycle.viewModelCompose)
                add("implementation", AndroidX.hilt.navigationCompose)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my project modules, where these configurations are needed, I added the custom plugin's id registered, also I deleted all the dependencies, plugins and features that those modules have in common.

```
plugins {
    id("com.example.myapplication.feature-plugin")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication.feature.login"
}

dependencies {
    // Navigation
    implementation(AndroidX.navigation.compose)

    // region Compose
    implementation(platform(AndroidX.compose.bom))
    implementation(AndroidX.compose.ui.text)
    implementation(AndroidX.compose.material.icons.core)
    implementation(AndroidX.compose.material.icons.extended)


    // Accompanist
    implementation(Google.accompanist.pager)
    implementation(Google.accompanist.pager.indicators)
    // endregion
}
```

When I build the project I get this error:

```
Unable to load class 'com.android.build.api.dsl.LibraryExtension'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

It all works fine if I don't include the following ***LibraryExtension***'s block in my custom plugin.

```
extensions.configure<LibraryExtension> {
               configureKotlinAndroid(this)
               defaultConfig.targetSdk = Consts.AndroidTargetSdk
               configureFlavors(this)
           }
```

Any idea of how to fix this problem and getting the plugin to be installed in my app modules recognising the ***LibraryExtension***?

**To note:**

- kotlin version = 1.7.10
- android plugin = 7.3.1
- gradle wrapper = 7.4.2

I also link the project's github repository [here](https://github.com/jempis/Gradle-Conventions).

Answer (score 0):

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75349099/5267209) for your question, i believe it is gonna solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for answering, although I had already included the build gradle plugin in the dependencies block of the buildSrc's build.gradle file.
I have added the github repository of this project in the post so that might be easier to see all the code.

Comment: change to compileOnly to implementation and try again